# MVC Razor Core2.0 Display calculation result in view

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the best way to display a calculation result is a Razor View? For example a  date diff. The model has a startDate and an endDate, how to show the diff in days?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you simply subtract one from the other. That will net you a `TimeSpan` object, which you can then utilize to get the days:

```
@((Model.endDate - Model.startDate).TotalDays)
```

That will return the total amount of days in the `TimeSpan` including a fractional component. If you're looking for something else, you may want to consider using a [custom formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) on it, or using something like [Humanizer library](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-timespan), which can give more human-readable results, like `1 day 2 hours 3 minutes".